# Why would -ms-grid-row not work if it comes before grid-row?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, css-grid

I have some CSS classes defined like this:

```
  .class-1,
  .class-2 {
    grid-row: 1/2;
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
  }
```

and they behave as expected. However, if I swap the order of the properties, i.e. change it to

```
  .class-1,
  .class-2 {
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    grid-row: 1/2;
  }
```

then IE doesn't see the -ms-grid-row property (according to the developer tools inspector, it's not there). Chrome sees grid-row in both cases.

Any idea why this could be or under what conditions this could happen? I've never encountered this issue before. I'm also using Sass, in case that's relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -ms-grid-row not work if it comes before grid-row?

Because IE has grid-row property, but it is not implemented in the standard way, and the browser will take the last property it recognizes (that is the default behavior in css).

If you want to limit `-ms-grid-row` only to IE and place it after you can use `@support` or `@media` (it's a hacky way) for example:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
}
```

Will work only in IE.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simplest sample but didn't reproduce the issue. The sample code is like below:

```css
.class-1,
.class-2 {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="class-1">1</div>
  <div class="class-2">2</div>
</div>
```

In IE, it can recognize `-ms-grid-row` property despite the order:

[image]

Also I think it's not related with sass as sass will eventually transfer into css when using. If the issue persists you could provide a minimal sample to reproduce it, then we can make a test and see what causes the issue.